# Why is my calculation using the law of total probability for this set wrong?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, summation

I have a set $\sigma = (1, 2, 3...n)$ following this pattern for n numbers. It is scrambled so that each permutation is equally likely. Let i be an index and let j be an index. I want the probability that i < j and that $\sigma(i) > \sigma(j)$.

We know intuitively that because of symmetry, P($i < j$) and P($\sigma(i) > \sigma(j)$) = 1/2.

However, I used the law of total probability to calculate P($\sigma(i) > \sigma(j)$), which is the same as P(i < j), right?.

Here it is: $\sum_{f=1}^n P(i<j|i=f)*P(i=f) = 1/n*\sum_{k=0}^{n} (n-k)/n $ and then using the formula for an arithmetic sum it becomes $1/2-1/(2*n)$.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Given that $i=f$, the probability that $j>i$ is what...  How many favorable choices for $j$ exist?  Out of how many remaining choices?  Remember that $j\neq i$.  If you are in fact allowing $i=j$ as a possible outcome, then note that $Pr(i=j)>0$ and that $1=Pr(i<j)+Pr(i=j)+Pr(i>j)$, which would imply that $Pr(i<j)\neq \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I wasn't allowing it as an outcome, that was my mistake. So what I did would be the correct method if i can = j?

Comment: Yes $~~~~~~~~~$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you condition on the event $\sigma(i)=f$, you have fixed one of the values of the permutation; $\sigma(j)$ is then equally likely to be any of the $n-1$ elements of $\{1,2,\dots,n\} \setminus \{f\}$. So the probability $\Pr[\sigma(i) < \sigma(j) \mid \sigma(i) = f]$ is not $\frac{n-k}{n}$ but $\frac{n-k}{n-1}$, and your calculation should now correctly give $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n-k}{n-1} \cdot \frac1n = \frac1{n(n-1)} \sum_{k=1}^n (n-k) = \frac1{n(n-1)} \cdot \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \frac12.$$

Comment: ah yes! thank you. and also just to confirm i < j = sigma(i)>sigma(j) right?

Comment: I guess I was assuming you fixed $i$ and $j$ and chose the permutation $\sigma$ at random. But if you randomly chose $i$ and $j$ (with the condition that $i \ne j$) then the same argument would apply to $\Pr[i<j]$ and $\Pr[i>j]$.